# How to query aggregated data with other columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by

Given is below record in `user_score` table where each user can have multiple score, user will diff user id can have same name and role. How to fetch average score along with `user_id`, `role` and `name`. I want to group by `user_id`.

So for my below table I am expecting result as:

```
Name   Role  Score  user_id
Jack   CEO     6      123
Jack   CEO     2      456
Tony   Dev     5      234
Sham    QA     3      678
```

**user_score table data :**

```
id     name    role     score    user_id
1      Jack    CEO       4        123
2      Jack    CEO       8        123
3      Tony    Dev       9        234
4      Jack    CEO       2        456
5      Tony    Dev       1        234
6      Sham    QA        3        678
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `group by`:

```
select id, name, role, avg(score), user_id
from user_score
group by id, name, role, user_id
```

P.S.: You can normalize the data because 3/5 columns are redundant (they're unnecessarily repeated). I would leave only `score` and `user_id` in this table, move `user_id`, `role` and `name` to the other and use `user_id` as a joining key.

Comment: @GMB of course I meant `avg`, my bad, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

While you might know that a given user_id always has the same name and role, PostgreSQL has no way of knowing that (other than you normalizing your data), so it needs instructions on what to report for more than one name within a given user_id.  You need to include a dummy aggregation on the extra columns.

```
select min(name) as name, min(role) as role, avg(score) as score, user_id 
    from user_score group by user_id
```

Rather than `min`, you could use `max` or `string_agg(distinct ...)`, or probably several other things